# git cherry-pick isn't cherry-picking commits

Tags: git, cherry-pick

Excuse my bad git but I had a git log like this:

```
commit fc9ab1fe1cfc2ac1e82e2de18a4244d94a7bb89f
Author: 
Date:   

    message 4

commit 3417248ab0953d715b3318f64635a825473bf73d
Author: 
Date:   

    message 3

commit da223a0b1e333a935b548a93f00263bb5b554cf7
Author: 
Date:   

    message 2

commit 1910a6cd9586e905258c6c9dcace2a7800a55f26
Author: 
Date:   

    message 1
```

I wanted to keep the earliest commit, do a different commit in place of the second commit and then put the third and fourth commits on top of that. e.g.

Old:
fc9ab1fe1cfc2ac1e82e2de18a4244d94a7bb89f
3417248ab0953d715b3318f64635a825473bf73d
da223a0b1e333a935b548a93f00263bb5b554cf7
1910a6cd9586e905258c6c9dcace2a7800a55f26

New:
fc9ab1fe1cfc2ac1e82e2de18a4244d94a7bb89f
3417248ab0953d715b3318f64635a825473bf73d
replacement_commit
1910a6cd9586e905258c6c9dcace2a7800a55f26

Here's how I got to "Old"

```
#changes
git add .
git commit -m "message1"
#changes
git add .
git commit -m "message2"
#changes
git add .
git commit -m "message3"
#changes
git add .
git commit -m "message4"
git push
```

Here is how I tried to make my changes

```
git pull
git reset 1910a6cd9586e905258c6c9dcace2a7800a55f26
git reset #removes all the later commits from staging
#make changes
git add .
git commit -m "replacement_commit"
#now to cherry pick the other two (which have already been pushed to a repository for this branch)
git cherry-pick 3417248ab0953d715b3318f64635a825473bf73d^..fc9ab1fe1cfc2ac1e82e2de18a4244d94a7bb89f
```

It doesn't work. Output:

```
-> % git cherry-pick 3417248ab0953d715b3318f64635a825473bf73d^..fc9ab1fe1cfc2ac1e82e2de18a4244d94a7bb89f
On branch my_branch
Cherry-pick currently in progress.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

and then use:

    git cherry-pick --continue

to resume cherry-picking the remaining commits.
If you wish to skip this commit, use:

    git cherry-pick --skip
```

Is there a way I can fix this or a better way I can be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I tried it without "^" and that worked!

```
git cherry-pick 3417248ab0953d715b3318f64635a825473bf73d..fc9ab1fe1cfc2ac1e82e2de18a4244d94a7bb89f
```